# Make with dependencies from a file

Tags: makefile

I want to write a Makefile that reads a file `list.txt` and produces `result.tar` containing the contents. If there is a change in either the `list.txt` file, or any of the files it points at, then `result.tar` should be rebuilt. How can I express this in a Makefile? The closest I have come is:

```
result.tar : list.txt
   cat list.txt | xargs tar -cf result.tar
```

But this omits the dependency on the contents of `list.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there should be something like this:

```
result.tar : list.txt $(shell cat list.txt)
   cat list.txt | xargs tar -cf result.tar
```

Or, a bit better (extracting `list.txt` to a variable and using automatic variables):

```
LIST_FILE := list.txt
result.tar : $(LIST_FILE) $(shell cat $(LIST_FILE))
   cat $< | xargs tar -cf $@
```

Comment: This will break if xargs invokes tar more than once.  Each invocation overwrites the tar file.  Just remove the xargs to make it work correctly.